# Number of events in one array within w minutes after any event in a second array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, time-complexity

I have two sorted arrays of unix time stamps (so integers representing times at which some events happen). Lets call the arrays ts1 and ts2. I want to find the number of events in ts1 that lie after w-minutes of any event in ts2. Let's say the method signature is (take the first and second arrays and window size then return number of events in ts1 that are within w minutes after any event in ts2):

```
critical_events(ts1,ts2,w)->int
```

Here are some test cases:

```
## Test cases.
ev = critical_events([.5,1.5,2.5],[1,2,3],.5)
print(ev==0)

ev = critical_events([1.4,1.4,2.7],[1,2,3],.5)
print(ev==2)

ev = critical_events([1.4,2.4,3.4],[1,2,3],.5)
print(ev==3)
```

I expect the length of the first array, n to be much larger than the length of the second one, m. Looking for efficient algorithms in terms of time and space and if possible, their average and worst case complexities in terms of n and m, time and space.

---

My attempt: instead of explaining my attempts, I'll just link to the code which should be self-explanatory (or at least better than what I can do in words): https://gist.github.com/ryu577/fdc22af4ed17d122a6aa25684597745b

Answer (score 1):

You are showing them as sorted, so my assumption is they are (need to be for this to work).
Because your first array is much larger than your second, you need to take your second in a for loop.

I am using example test case 2:ev = critical_events([1.4,1.4,2.7],[1,2,3],.5)
Next you can use a binary search on the first element of ts2 + interval (1 + 0.5) = 1.5.

Your startIndex is 0 and endIndex is 2. So in first compare you take all elements.

Doing a binary search will result in index 2 in ts1. Note: Because you have equal element in your array, you need to go right until you get higher number. What you can tell now is that 2.7 (and all elements after if there where any) are the element what lies after 1.5. Count is ts2.lenght - foundindex.

Now you can set your start index to 2. because you know, all on the left of this index is smaller and will not lie after 1.5 sec.
You take element2 and do a binary search, you will find index 2 ( 2.5 < 2.7), again:

Count = Count +  ts2.lenght - foundindex.

To my knowledge, this is the fastest method. I believe the speed is Log(n).m.

Comment: Thanks! This seems very similar to critical_events_v2 here: https://gist.github.com/ryu577/fdc22af4ed17d122a6aa25684597745b. The run-time complexity might be better than m log(n) since we search over successively smaller n's as the for-loop over m progresses.